# Python SDK Install Guide on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, sdk, raspberry-pi3, nao-robot

I follow [this page](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/python/install_guide.html#linux) to install python SDK on raspberry pi 3. When i run "`import naoqi`" for Checking the installation of the Python SDK, I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "naoqi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import qi
  File "qi/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from _qi import Application as _Application
ImportError: ./_qi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I think i maybe set wronge path in this code:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/python-sdk
```

My question is, what is `/path/to/python-sdk` ?
I set once this path:`export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/include/python2.7` , and once set this path: `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/nao/Downloads/Python-2.7.12`

but i see that error again. 
How must i do?

Comment: have you run the naoqi setup? you may need to complie naoqi first before you can import it. Unless that is a binary.

Comment: @SKipp, No i did not run naoqi setup. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

`/path/to/python-sdk` would be the absolute path to where you extracted `pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-x.x-linux32.tar.gz` that you have to download.